# Using MailKit to retrieve emails from gmail

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm using below code to retrieve the emails. But I'm getting a Socket exception when trying to connect the server (client.Connect(uri, cancel.Token);).

Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out

```
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using MailKit.Net.Pop3;

namespace TestMail
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

            using (var client = new Pop3Client ()) {

            var Server  = "gmail.com";
            var Port = "995";
            var UseSsl = false;
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "abc");
            var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource ();
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format("pop{0}://{1}:{2}", (UseSsl ? "s" : ""), Server, Port));

            //Connect to email server
            client.Connect(uri, cancel.Token);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate (credentials, cancel.Token);

            //Fetch Emails
            for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++) {
                var message = client.GetMessage (i);
                Console.WriteLine ("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
            }

            //Disconnect Connection
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you need to use `pop.gmail.com` and not just `gmail.com` as the server string.

Comment: After making the change am getting a different exception at same place -- Unhandled Exception:
MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3ProtocolException: The POP3 server has unexpectedly disconnected.

Comment: When I made useSsl as true, it is connecting but throws an authentication exception ---- Unhandled Exception:
MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3ProtocolException: POP3 server did not respond with a +OK response to the AUTH command. And when I login into my gmail account it has sign in prevented. Does it mean gmail is blocking my authentication and is there any way to unblock it?

Comment: Yes, it means that Google is blocking it. You need to go into your GMail Settings and enable POP3 support. You will probably also need to enable support for "less secure applications" (either that or register as a Google developer and get an OAuth2 token and start using OAuth2 authentication).

Answer (score 0):

use the following code i just test it in one of my projects and its working well

```
   using (var client = new Pop3Client()) {
 // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS) 
 client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true; 
 client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
 client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", "995", true);
 client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2"); 
 client.Authenticate(MailUsername, MailPassword);
..
....
......
}
```